# Why is 'my_global.h' from libmysqlclient-dev is missing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, package-management, mysql

There's package libmysqlclient-dev, providing MySQL API. In Ubuntu versions before 20.04 it contains header file '/usr/include/mysql/my_global.h', but in 20.04 there's no such file in package, as well as some other files.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/bionic/amd64/libmysqlclient-dev/filelist

https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/focal/amd64/libmysqlclient-dev/filelist

Can anybody explain, why is that so, and how can one work around this to compile application, which depends on this header?

Comment: Use MariaDB instead? https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=my_global.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out, that my_global.h doesn't contain any necessary information for work with database, therefore it was deleted in new Ubuntu releases (and my_global.h in libmariadb-dev is also empty), so it can be safe deleted from any dependencies. In my case, as I found out, it was used only to include math.h and TRUE/FALSE constants.

Comment: For my purposes, on Ubuntu 20.04, I have created an effectively-empty my_global.h file (containing only comments about its purpose) rather than change my umpteen source files that reference this header.  It is unfathomable to me that the maintainers made such a decision!  If they don't want to maintain a bunch of includes that THEY deem unnecessary, seems to me they should at least provide an EMPTY my_global.h file so we don't in turn have to make unnecessary changes to OUR code.  Sheesh.